# Nested list in android with listview from several xml files

Tags: android, xml, parsing, listview, nested

I am creating an app that has several `Buttons` on the first screen. Every `Button` will parse a separate `XML` file and is supposed to create a nested list from that information.

All the `XML` files have this structure:

```
<blalist>
<house>
     <name>Blaname1</name>
     <eaddress>195 bla steet</eaddress>
     <caddress>195 bla strasse</caddress>
     <telephone>123456</telephone>
</house>
<house>
     <name>Blaname2</name>
     <eaddress>15 bla steet</eaddress>
     <caddress>15 bla strasse</caddress>
     <telephone>12345685</telephone>
</house>
</blalist>
```

After clicking the first button i would like to generate a `ListView` consisting out of only the names from tag "name". So the list should only show Blaname1,Blaname2...
After clicking on one of the names all the other tags should be displayed as content;
 tags "eaddress","caddress","telephone" and three extra buttons.

Basically a 3 screens scenario. First page with the main buttons. Second page shows a list generated only with the names. Third screen shows the details of the specific name clicked.

How do i go about that? I found loads of info for parsing xml to `ListView` and some info about `ExpandableListView` but i couldnt really wrap my head around of how to go about this one. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is parse your XML and structure the data in the format that is supported by the `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` class.

1) For groups
`List<HashMap<String, String>> lstGroups`

2) For sub items of groups
`List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> lstGroupItems`

and then you can use `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), lstGroups,
                R.layout.group_row, // Group item layout XML.
                new String[] { "Group Item" }, // the key that will identify group in `lstGroups`.
                new int[] { R.id.row_name }, // ID of each group item.-Data
                lstGroupItems, // childData describes second-level
                R.layout.child_row, // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] { "Sub Item" }, // Keys that will identify child items in `lstGroupItems`
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child }
        );
setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

You can refer this example

[Expandable ListView in ANDROID using SimpleExpandableListAdapter, a simple example.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/)

**Added :**

I think you should use SQLiteDatabase if you are having large amount of data or else you can structure your data in the following format

`Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapHouses;`

Here the key will be the house name and its value will be again the Map which will hold the house properties and the corresponding value.

You will be requiring access to `mapHouses` accross diffrent activity so you can have the same in your application context i.e the `Application` class and pass the house name to the activity that neds to display the house details. But you will end up holding large data into the memory and which can be lost if your application is killed by Android.

Comment: Thank you Vishal. I dont want to have an expandable list though cause that makes things look messy. I will have a lot of data at the end. I just would like to have it go to a new screen and display the data. Like this: Click on mainbutton, nameslist from xml, when clicked on one name another page opens that includes all the details like eaddress,caddress and phone number. Basically it has 3 screens. First shows the main buttons. Second screen shows the names list. Third screen shows details of the name clicked. what could i do?

Comment: Thank you vishal. Wil take a look at your suggestion and get back to you here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in response to Vishal your question is actually asking how to build an entire application.

You need to build

- a main activity with a button that launches your list activity
- a list activity that displays a list of names
- a detail activity that can be used to display the details associated with a name

In addition you'll need to decide on a technology you'll use to deserialize the XML and store it somehow. I'd recommend XStream to deserialize but there're loads of options and you may already have a preference.

Then you'll want to store the Name objects you've deserialized. I'd recommend that you use ORMLite or DB4O.

You'll need a way to load a list of all names and a way to load the details of a particular name from whichever persistence technology you've chosen.

Your best bet is to try and do those things and then post new questions about specific problems you have trying to build the application.

Hope that helps... and isn't just teaching grandma to suck eggs

Comment: Hehe. Love your last comment! Thanks a lot Paul. Will definitely look into your things. i already built the same app with jquery mobile but that is just too slow so i want to make it native. So you are also suggesting to utilize a database. Will look into everything you suggested and get back here. Thanks again!

Comment: what is the difference between parsing and deserializing an xml? i am a bit confused. Does one of them have better performance? do i necessarily need to store it. cant i just "read it out" when needed?

Comment: Maybe there's not really a difference.. I'd argue that parsing is just the process of getting sense out of it. So I parse it when I read it.. but that deserialization is the process of turning the XML into one or more objects.